# How to call require in protractor based on "for loop"?

Tags: angularjs, protractor, gulp-protractor

I am using require to call more than one .js file in protractor. I need to call a js file more than one time using for loop(for require function).

I need to pass more than one element in to another require file.(Collection). Problem is , the require is working only one time for a loop.(for any maximum value).

```
for(var i=0;i<count;i++)
{
require('../e2e/XYZ.js');
}
```

For each value of "i" ,require file has to be executed, whereas its getting executed only once.

Comment: Tried with forEach loop also. Ending up with same problem.(Loop is getting executed only once)  arrary.forEach(function() {
console.log("xyz" + arraryElements);
require('../e2e/xyz.js');
});

Comment: Did you try with using function inside for loop? For loop usually executes very quickly and require might get delayed. Here's how - `for(var i=0;i<count;i++)(function(){//Your code to use require})();`.

Comment: It is not the right way to use Node.js modules, `require` will load the file once and then cache it. To fix it you need to rethink your approach and export some kind of a function from your module, require a module once before your loop starts `var doSomething = require('./module');` and then run function in a loop `for (..) { doSomething(); }`

Comment: Tried this.  for(var i=0;i<count;i++)(function(){require('../e2e/XYZ.js')})(); Still loop is getting executed only once. Any other way??